# Why I can't plot something that isn't a scalar or a 1D or a (2, n) array like?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, valueerror

I'm new to python and I need to plot graphs for my university courses. I get a value error on this code and I don't know how to solve it. I have tried to convert V and m with `np.asscalar` but I don't get any improvements.

> ValueError: err must be a scalar or a 1D or (2, n) array-like

I think the problem is in the errorbar but I really am struggling with it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

m=np.array([np.loadtxt('masse.txt')]) 
sigma_m=np.array([np.loadtxt('errore_masse.txt')])
lati=np.array([np.loadtxt('lati.txt')])
sigma_lati=np.array(np.loadtxt('errore_lati.txt'))
h=np.array([np.loadtxt('altezze.txt')]) 
sigma_h=np.array([np.loadtxt('errore_altezza.txt')])

dc=np.array([6.45, 8.56, 10.45, 10.46])
hc=np.array([16.25, 40.80, 75., 17.67])
lpe=np.array([8.56])
a=np.array([7.41])
hpe=np.array([37.3])
lb=np.array([10.46])

rc=dc/2
Vc=2*np.pi*a**2 *hc
sigma_rc=sigma_lati/2
sigma_Vc=Vc*2*(0.01/dc)

Vpe=6*lpe*a*hpe
sigma_Vpe=((lpe*a)**2 *(0.01)**2 +(lpe*hpe)**2 *(0.01)**2 +(hpe*a)**2 *(0.01)**2)

Vp=lb**2
sigma_Vp=2*Vp*(0.01/lb)

V=np.array([np.loadtxt('volumi.txt')])
sigma_V=np.array([np.loadtxt('errore_volumi.txt')])

def line (x, a, q):
    """funzione retta
    """
    return a*x+q

plt.figure('Grafico massa-volume oggetti di ottone')
plt.errorbar(m, sigma_m, V, sigma_V, marker='.', fmt='.')

popt, pcov=curve_fit(m, V, line)

a_fit, q_fit= popt

sigma_a_fit, sigma_q_fit=np.sqrt(pcov.diagonal())

print(a_fit, q_fit, sigma_a_fit, sigma_q_fit)
x=np.linspace(10.675, 34.080, 10)
plt.plot(x, line(x, a_fit, q_fit))
plt.xlabel('Volume [mm$^3$]')
plt.ylabel('Massa [g]')
plt.grid (ls='dashed', which='both')

plt.show()
```

Comment: When I look up pyplot.errorbar the parameter list doesn't match the parameters you passed: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html#examples-using-matplotlib-pyplot-errorbar -- what version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The value error you are getting is because you mixed up your values in the error bar. For usage you should check out [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html).

Your problems stem from this line:

```
plt.errorbar(m, sigma_m, V, sigma_V, marker='.', fmt='.')
```

First you should check the shapes of all those variables using `m.shape`, `sigma_m.shape`, ect. They need to all have the same shape, or the second 2 values should be your error which you have switched. If they are multidimensional arrays then you need to flatten or use an index to get the array you want. Assuming `m` is your x data and `V` is your y data, you should have something like this:

```
plt.errorbar(m, V, xerr=sigma_m, yerr=sigma_V, marker='.', fmt='.')
```

Since you had a multidimensional array with a (1,N) use:

```
plt.errorbar(m[0], V[0], xerr=sigma_m[0], yerr=sigma_V[0], marker='.', fmt='.')
```

Comment: i checked and the shape of all four parameters in the errorbar is (1, 5), i also tried to put xerr and yerr but nothing has changed. should i try to change the shape of the parameters?

Comment: Thats part of your error, you need to have a 1D array not 2D. You can remove the 1 by indexing the values like `m[0]`, `V[0]` and so on

Comment: You are welcome, consider upvoting or marking the question as answered so others can benefit.